# UIWebView, input type, how to add percent value

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a UIWebView, it has a table, and I want it 80% of the UIWebView size, but in de NSString I use as html:

```
"<table width = \"80%\", align = \"center\">"
```

I have a warning:

```
Invalid conversion specifier '"'**
```

because it is waiting for a d or @ or whatever.

I try to see the html, using NSLog, and the % is missing

```
<table width = "80", align = "center">
```

how can I tell the NSString the % value? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use '%%' instead of '%'

```
NSLog(@"<table width = \"80%%\", align = \"center\">");
```

I assume you are defining NSString using stringWithFormat so you should use '%%'. escape sequence for % is %%.

Comment: omw you champ! no wonder my images shows only 100px instead of 100% lol vote this up!